# Modelling Length of Hospital Stay, Poisson Regression or Cox Regression Analysis

Tags: survival, cox-model, poisson-regression

I would like to find out what people thought about the better or more widely accepted way to model hospital Length of Stay (LOS) is?

LOS can be thought of as count data (number of days) with a right-skew (most patients are discharged in the first few days, then there're stragglers with late discharges), or as survival data (time to event of discharge).

Comment: What is your goal in the analysis and what is your data like? If you have many censored observations, Cox or other survival models will probably work better "out-of-the-box". Both will give interpretable coefficients for covariates. Poisson may be easier to work with if you're forecasting and might be easier to explain to people who haven't seen survival analysis before.

Comment: LOS is highly nontrivial to model. See my answer here:
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207999/which-is-more-appropriate-poisson-or-regular-linear-regression/208027#208027

Comment: I have data on an inpatient elective surgical cohort and a measure of postoperative morbidity at fixed time points after surgery, eg days 3,7,14. The patients eventually get discharged (alive or dead, mostly alive). I want to do two things, see if the measure of postoperative morbidity at day 3 is predictive for the length of stay, and validate the measure of morbidity (currently no gold standard) by linking the measure to prolongation of LOS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is more appropriate? Poisson or regular linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207999/which-is-more-appropriate-poisson-or-regular-linear-regression)