# Which algorithm can I use for predicting length of stay in coming year based on historical claims data?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, prediction

I have two years historical health claims data of one thousand members. Based on this two years data, I have to predict length of stay in hospital in 3rd year for all members. here is the data sample.

```
Year MembID x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  LengthOfStay

2010    1   6   35  0   3   0   0   4   1   
2010    1   8   35  0   5   0   0   3   0   
2009    1   5   35  0   5   0   0   3   3   
2009    1   3   35  0   8   2   0   8   0   
2010    2   6   30  0   3   3   2   4   0   
2010    2   8   30  0   5   0   0   3   0   
2009    2   5   30  0   5   0   0   3   0   
2010    2   5   30  1   5   0   2   2   0   
2009    3   5   55  1   5   1   2   2   0   
2010    3   10  55  1   5   0   2   2   0   
2010    3   5   55  1   5   1   2   2   0   
2009    3   10  55  1   5   0   0   2   0   
2010    4   5   24  1   5   0   0   2   0   
2009    4   3   24  1   8   0   0   2   0   
2009    5   10  65  1   5   1   2   4   5   
2009    5   5   65  1   5   0   2   3   0   
2010    5   6   65  1   3   0   0   4   0   
2010    5   4   65  1   5   0   0   4   0
```

I did the classification with randomforest. How can I proceed further for prediction on 2011?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207999/which-is-more-appropriate-poisson-or-regular-linear-regression/208027#208027

Comment: Is each line one claim?  Over this time period, can we treat the aging of members as a minor effect? (sure, claims are higher for 60 year olds than 40 year olds, but that's 20 years, not 1 or 2).